# Сортировка массива данных из файла по первым символам

Tags: java

Задание: вывести в файл список всех смартфонов, сортированных по серийному номеру(уникальные 4 символа типа int, которые стоят в начале каждой строки). Для начала их нужно прочитать из файла. Вопрос: как сортировать строки, прочитанные из файла, только по первым четырем символам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен `Collections.sort` и свой `Compartor`

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

//Add elements to Arraylist
arrayList.add("1345245556");
arrayList.add("3346346245");
arrayList.add("5345442423");
arrayList.add("2234235436");
arrayList.add("4235346323");

IgnoreCaseComparator icc = new IgnoreCaseComparator();
Collections.sort(arrayList, icc);
```

Второй аргумент метода Sort - компаратор:

```
class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
    //сравниваем не строки целиком, но только первые их 4 символа
    return strA.substring(0,4).compareToIgnoreCase(strB.substring(0,4));
  }
}
```

Comment: Может быть это глупый вопрос, но для чего strA и strB и почему из сразу два?

Comment: @PoGostu, компаратор по очереди сравнивает все строки. Но сравнивать их может только по две за раз. В результате получается число по принипу больше-меньше. В итоге все строки выстраиваются в порядке этих полученных чисел. Как-то так)

Comment: Так, это я понял) А как компаратор передается в Collections.sort(arrayList, icc); ?

Comment: @PoGostu, ну так я ж написал... `IgnoreCaseComparator icc = new IgnoreCaseComparator();
Collections.sort(arrayList, icc);`

Comment: Просто я совсем новичок в Java, получается что компаратор передается из класса IgnoreCaseComparator?

Comment: @PoGostu, нет. Вы сначала описываете класс-компаратор, потом создаёте его экземпляр, потом передаёте этот экземпляр в качестве аргумента метода sort

Comment: IgnoreCaseComparator icc = new IgnoreCaseComparator(); это экземпляр?

Comment: @PoGostu, обхявляется переменная типа IgnoreCaseComparator с именем icc. После этого ей присваивается ссылка на объект типа IgnoreCaseComparator, коий создаётся через оператор `new`. Да, кратко - это экземпляр.

Comment: Можно сразу использовать структуру для хранения отсортированного множества, например TreeSet и в конструктор в качестве аргумента передать Comporator, тогда метод compare() будет отрабатывать каждый раз когда вы изменяете множество, и при добавлении новых элементов не нужно будет каждый раз вызывать метод sort()